# Вывод и ввод состояния Checkbox из таблицы SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox

Есть *listview* с *textview* и *checkbox*. Есть таблица `TTable` со столбцами: текст в `COLUMN_SUMMARY`, состояние (0 и 1) в `COLUMN_CHECK_STATUS`.

Текст выводится, а состояние синхронизировать не могу.

Нужно, чтобы состояние загружалось из COLUMN_CHECK_STATUS, при изменении состояния данные обновлялись.

Прошу помочь.

Код:

```
private void fillData() {
    String[] from = new String[]{TTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY};
    //String[] fromChk = new String[] {TTable.COLUMN_CHECK_STATUS};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.label};
    //int[] toChk = new int[] { R.id.check };
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //adapterChk = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, fromChk, toChk, 0);
    //setListAdapter(adapterChk);
}
```

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` не предназначен для таких действий. Вам надо написать собственный адаптер, который будет реализовывать требуемую функциональность.